# What is the name of this kind of algebra?

Tags: terminology, universal-algebra

Consider a set $S$ with a single binary operation $*$. Suppose that the only equations $*$ satisfies are of the form $t=t$, for every term $t$. What would be the name of this kind of algebra? Of course, the signature doesn't have to consist of a single binary operation. It could be any number of operations with any number of arities. But the essential thing is, they only satisfy equations of the form $t=t$. Is there a standard name for this kind of algebra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume that when you say *equation* you mean *universally quantified equation*, or *identity*.

If $\mathcal V$ is a variety, then an algebra that generates $\mathcal V$ is called *generic* for $\mathcal V$. Free algebras on sufficiently many generators are generic, but generic algebras need not be free.

This applies here. Suppose that $\langle S; *\rangle$ only satisfies trivial identities. Then $S$ is generic for the variety of algebras with a single binary operation. But it need not be free. For example, $S' = S\times T$ where $T$ is a $2$-element semigroup will satisfy the same identities as $S$ (only trivial ones), but will not be free.